# What happened if i don't remove observer from nsnotification center?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, notifications

As I thought, if i don't remove observer when instance is deallocd, next time the notification has been posted, program will crash because of an unknown selector exception.

But when i wrote some test code, found it is not like that, every thing just fine, noting happened. And I'm sure dealloc method is called.

So what's wrong whit it?

Comment: There's a reason they call it "undefined behavior".

Comment: So what is the question? You removed the observer and your code crashed, you wrote the code differently and it worked. So what is the issue?

Comment: I don't remove it, and nothing wrong, everything just fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apple is taking care of it for you but I think its good form to remove observer anyway. It could pose problems and for all you know cause random errors down the line.

Comment: How "apple taking care of it", can I find some document about it?

Comment: notifications are listening rather than a delegate which is sending a message to a specific object. You are just deallocating and then stop listening.